# Postgresql 9.2.1, Couldn't enter into single user mode

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

In postgresql 9.2.1, i tried to open my database XXX in single user mode to perform the vacuum freeze operation. Because the database didn't accept any commands to avoid wraparound dataloss. But it fails to enter into single user mode. It showed the below warning message and froze.

[image: Warning message while trying to enter in single user mode]

What are the possible reasons for this warning ? how can i resolve it ? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exact commands run?

Comment: **postgres.exe --single -D "./../data" <DB_NAME>** - command to enter the single user mode. I also checked that no other postgresql is running.

Comment: Weird, and you get no interactive prompt you can type queries at? I wonder if there's a broken critical system index somewhere. Try again with the extra option `-P`

Comment: Sorry, actually it took sometime to enter into the single user mode(which is not usual). Now, i can run my vacuum process in single user mode. Thank you @CraigRinger